# Angular 4 - show/hide element in DOM using Id of element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, show-hide

I want to show a button (or append it to its parent element) with a specific `Id` when a function is called but I don't know how to access the element in the component class.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">

    <button [attr.id]="'undoBtn'+i" *ngIf="showBtn" class="editBtn" md-raised-button color="primary"> 
        <md-icon>undo</md-icon>Undo
    </button>

    <button (click)=showUndoBtn(i) md-raised-button color="primary">Test</button>
</div>
```

**Component class:**

```
private showBtn = false;

showUndoBtn(btnId: number) {
    // show btn with id btnId in DOM
}
```

The undo button must be hidden at the beginning and when Test button is clicked, it should appear. I tried using `*ngIf` and `@ViewChild()`  but it can not be used for several buttons with different id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep the selected button id in showBtn property.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">

        <button [attr.id]="'undoBtn'+i" *ngIf="showBtn===i" class="editBtn" md-raised-button color="primary"> 
            <md-icon>undo</md-icon>Undo
        </button>

        <button (click)=showUndoBtn(i) md-raised-button color="primary">Test</button>
 </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
showBtn=-1;

showUndoBtn(index){
  this.showBtn=index;
}
```

Comment: I need a solution when i click on the same div it will close the opened div. is there any solution?

Comment: yes, but if i click outside the div that means any part of the body it will also close the opened div

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way where you don't need to call separate function to implement

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">

        <button [attr.id]="'undoBtn'+i" *ngIf="showBtn===i" class="editBtn" md-raised-button color="primary"> 
            <md-icon>undo</md-icon>Undo
        </button>

        <button (click)='showBtn=i' md-raised-button color="primary">Test</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use properties on your repeated items, something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">

    <button [attr.id]="'undoBtn'+i" *ngIf="item.showButton" class="editBtn" md-raised-button color="primary"> 
        <md-icon>undo</md-icon>Undo
    </button>

    <button (click)=showUndoBtn(item) md-raised-button color="primary">Test</button>
</div>
```

And your component:

```
showUndoBtn(item) {
    // show btn with id btnId in DOM
    item.showButton = true;
}
```